# Rater un éléphant dans le couloir

Tags: sens, expressions

D'après [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rater_un_%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant_dans_un_couloir), cette expression signifie « viser très mal ».

Peut-elle aussi s'utiliser pour dire « ne pas voir ce qui est flagrant » ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OUI !** L'expression peut être comprise dans un certain contexte.

> [Rater](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rater/66624) un éléphant dans le couloir

Signifie littéralement,

> Viser sans réussir à atteindre un éléphant dans le couloir.

On peut [viser](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/viser/82186?q=viser#81219) avec une arme ([tenir en joue](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tenir_en_joue)), mais on vise surtout grâce à ses yeux d'où le sens "rechercher".

De là, "Rater" peut se transformer en "Rechercher sans réussir à trouver".

Et pour ne pas trouver un éléphant qu'on recherche dans un couloir, il faut vraiment "ne pas voir ce qui est flagrant".

Selon moi la phrase est compréhensible.

Comment: Lire la réponse de "comet hapax d'ajax" pour plus d'info.

Answer (score 7):

#### Réponse courte

1. Peut-elle aussi s'utiliser pour dire: « ne pas voir ce qui est flagrant » ?

**Non.**

2. Existe-t-il une autre expression pour le dire ?

On peut utiliser l'expression suivante, moyennant quelques modifications de la phrase.

> **[comme le nez au milieu de la figure](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme_le_nez_au_milieu_de_la_figure)**

#### Plus textuel

« Rater un éléphant dans un couloir » contient « rater » (alternativement : « manquer ») : on a une cible, on cherche à la toucher, et on passe à côté alors que la cible occupe tout l'espace et ne peut pas bouger. On est vraiment très mauvais, n'est-ce pas ?

« *The elephant in the room* » ne se traduit pas directement. On peut trouver des équivalents en fonction du contexte.

Dans le cas d'une réunion débutant par « *To begin with the elephant in the room* », je ne connais pas d'équivalent direct, [comme Eusebius](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17876/7224).

Pour caractériser quelque chose de visible et d'immanquable, on peut dire que c'est « [comme le nez au milieu de la figure](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme_le_nez_au_milieu_de_la_figure) ».

Comment: +1 pour la présentation réponse courte / réponse longue

Comment: Merci @Chop ! Donc pour toi, je ne peux pas utiliser cette expression dans le sens décrit par Kii dans sa réponse ?

Comment: @Arone [Kii extrapole](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/17885/7224) à partir du sens courant. Il a raison, cette phrase pourra être compréhensible. À condition que ton interlocuteur ne reste pas bloqué sur la signification originale de l'expression, ce qui est souvent un risque avec les idiomatiques. Je ne prendrais pas ce risque lorsqu'une autre expression est utilisée de façon bien plus courante pour exprimer la même chose. Mais ce n'est bien entendu que mon avis.

Comment: @Arone Voir [la réponse de comet](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/17893/7224) qui me contredit et cite un exemple d'usage de l'expression dans le sens que vous souhaitez.

Comment: Merci @Chop pour ton humilité!

Comment: @Arone Le but des Stack Exchange pour moi n'est pas d'avoir le dernier mot, mais d'aider au mieux à trouver une bonne réponse. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Un [dictionnaire](https://books.google.com/books?id=d-wcAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22dans%20un%20couloir%2C%20ont%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20corrig%C3%A9s.%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22maladresse%20insigne%22) de Bernet/Rézeau parle d'une hyperbole dans des types de locutions avec des verbes comme *rater* (et vache), tel qu'une [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17889) le mentionne ; on parle de « maladresse insigne ». On la trouve dans quelques oeuvres comme [*Le carrefour des solitudes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-s09AAAAIAAJ&dq=editions%3AjhPFsKYQYsAC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20dans%20un%20couloir%22), de [Mégret](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_M%C3%A9gret), 1957, récipiendaire du prix Fémina ; la personne est envoyée au front : « [...] *il est tellement myope qu'il raterait un éléphant dans un couloir.* ». Ou chez [Laferrière](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dany_Laferri%C3%A8re) (*Ac*., F2) dans [*Le goût des jeunes filles*](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20dans%20un%20couloir!%20me%20crie%20le%20gendarme%22), 1992 : « *Il ne pourrait même pas toucher un éléphant dans un couloir! me crie le gendarme.* ». Des contextes avec l'arme à feu et la maladresse, vu l'état ou les facultés, au conditionnel. L'expression semble assez rare, du moins à l'écrit ([Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=inauthor:%22Pierre%20R%C3%A9zeau%22#tbm=bks&q=%22%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20dans%20un%20couloir%22) ; dans [Openlexique](http://www.lexique.org/moteur/RechCoOc.php), deux foix avec *éléphant*, dont une avec *viser*, et une fois avec *vache*).

---

Bernet/Rézeau notent un [emploi](https://books.google.com/books?id=d-wcAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20dans%20un%20couloir%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phan%20dans%20un%20couloir%22) très récent avec *éléphant dans le couloir*, dans une comparaison sans les verbes dont il était question précédemment : « *c'est ainsi que les défauts* [d'une équipe de rugby] *pointés du doigt samedi dernier, et aussi visibles qu'un éléphant dans un couloir, ont été corrigés.* » (*Sud Ouest*, 2 novembre 2007, p.11). Certainement ici dans le sens de *flagrant* dont une [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17885) traite ; *ne pas remarquer ce qui est aussi visible qu'un éléphant dans un couloir* réussirait peut-être à évoquer le sens qu'on voulait attribuer à la locution en question, quoique avec lourdeur. On peut simplement avoir un faible sens de l'observation, être distrait ou inattentif, ne pas voir ce qui saute aux yeux etc.. Ailleurs on se questionne sur l'apport de l'« elephant in the room » en anglais au sens de flagrant, qui paraît évident, ici. Ce n'est pas le même éléphant pour ainsi dire.<sup>1</sup> Si il y a *malaise* parce qu'on est à l'étroit, ou pour une raison personnelle, il y a malaise ; si il s'agit d'une question qui est sur toutes les lèvres, pour laquelle on s'inquiète, qui est d'une importance capitale, on l'abordera en premier lieu. Si c'est un secret connu de tous mais qu'on n'aborde pas, il s'agit familièrement d'un *secret de polichinelle*. Le mammifère surdimensionné n'est pas la référence la plus usuelle dans ces contextes, à mon avis.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> La comparaison des emplois entre le [français](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20dans%20le%20*%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20dans%20un%20*%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20dans%20une%20*%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20*_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C*_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Best_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btuer_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btu%C3%A9_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brepr%C3%A9sente_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvu_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brepr%C3%A9sentant_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvoir_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bc%27est_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9tait_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btue_VERB%20un%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20dans%20le%20magasin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20dans%20un%20magasin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20*_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20blanc_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20fossile_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20sauvage_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20d%27_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20antique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20africain_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20femelle_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20m%C3%A2le_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20marin_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant%20indien_ADJ%3B%2Cc0) et l'[anglais](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elephant%20in%20the%20room%2Celephant%20on%20the%20roof%2Celephant%20in%20the%20*%2Celephant%20on%20the%20*%2C*_ADJ%20elephant&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celephant%20in%20the%20room%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celephant%20on%20the%20roof%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Celephant%20in%20the%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Belephant%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20in%20the%20room%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20in%20the%20Punic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20in%20the%20moon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20in%20the%20living%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20in%20the%20menagerie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20in%20the%20jungle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20in%20the%20forest%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20in%20the%20Jardin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20in%20the%20middle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Celephant%20on%20the%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Belephant%20on%20the%20hands%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20on%20the%20stage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20on%20the%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20on%20the%20banks%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20on%20the%20other%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20on%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20on%20the%20roof%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20on%20the%20side%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20on%20the%20obverse%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belephant%20on%20the%20ground%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwhite_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAfrican_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIndian_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwild_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhuge_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfossil_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Byoung_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreat_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blarge_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bold_ADJ%20elephant%3B%2Cc0) dépasse le cadre de la question ; ce pourrait être une différence qualitative, et l'*elephant in the room* pèse (de plus en plus) fort en anglais, semble-t-il. Par ailleurs on a [seeing the elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seeing_the_elephant) dans un contexte différent du couloir (AmE ; le soldat ayant été confronté au combat ; par extension acquérir une expérience en en payant un prix élevé etc.). En français, l'[éléphant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant) apparaît dans diverses expressions comme *avoir une [mémoire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9moire) d'éléphant* (exceptionnelle), *faire d'une [mouche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mouche) un éléphant* (vieux ; exagérer) ou *être comme un éléphant dans un magasin de [porcelaine](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/porcelaine)* (maladroit) ; on disait aussi en argot de la marine que tout civil était un éléphant ; on associe aussi l'éléphant à la *capacité créatrice puissante, lourde, généralement sans raffinement*.. (*TLFi*, [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant/28378/locution)).</sub>

Comment: Vos réponses sont toujours aussi inspirantes par les recherches qui les accompagnent. Je pense que le sens de « flagrant » pour l'éléphant dans le couloir dérive d'une assimilation avec l'_elephant in the room_, mais c'est l'usage qui fait la langue. :)

Comment: @Chop Merci, il me fallait rectifier une impression laissée par mon commentaire sous la question (_l'existence même de l'expression est incertaine_). Je n'ai personnellement jamais entendu l'expression avant la recherche, mais l'assimilation dont vous parlez est plausible, quoique l'aspect imposant de l'animal soit flagrant et les déductions qui découlent du manque d'observation d'un tel mastodonte, naturelles. p.s. je ne vous contredis pas, l'exemple au rugby n'inclut pas le verbe _rater_, mais seulement l'éléphant dans le couloir.

Answer (score 4):

Non, je ne l'ai jamais entendue utiliser dans ce sens-là. Peut-être avez-vous à l'esprit "*the elephant in the room*" de la langue anglaise (expression qui n'est pas du tout utilisé en français, je ne suis même pas sûr qu'elle ait un équivalent).

Answer (score 2):

**Oui!** Elle sera comprise, il y a même une expression équivalente :

> Rater une vache dans un couloir

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression

Comment: Je n'avais jamais entendu mais l'expression existe [tel que noté chez Bernet/Rézeau](https://books.google.com/books?id=d-wcAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22dans%20un%20couloir%2C%20ont%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20corrig%C3%A9s.%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22maladresse%20insigne%22). J'en ai pris connaissance ici avant de lire Bernet/Rézeau. +1